# Identify the species of bamboo shown

Tags: identification, bamboo

[image]

kindly identify the bamboo species shown in the picture

Comment: Please say where in the world this picture was taken - and how tall is the plant, its not easy to see the top of the photo, too much light.  How long's it been planted and has it spread? And need a clear close up of a stem and sheath/leaf connection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this is a Gracilis bamboo.